# Why am I getting a "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error in this code?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to use the update query but it shows the following syntax error:

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[Item Name]='bulb',[Quantity Type]='pcs',[Quantity]='470',[Item Price (in Rs.)]=' at line 1'"

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(con))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE inventory Set [Item Name]=@itname,[Quantity Type]=@qtype,[Quantity]=@qty,[Item Price (in Rs.)]=@itprice,[Supplier]=@supl WHERE [pid]=@lpid";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lpid", lbl_dpid.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itname", txtbox_itemname.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qtype", cmbox_qtype.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", txtbox_qty.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itprice", txtbox_itprice.Text.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supl", txtbox_supplier.Text);

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Update?", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In the database table, Data Type for pid, item Price (in Rs.) and Quantity is int and rest is varchar.
[This is what the design looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiAQg.png)

Comment: Your column name really is named `Item Price (in Rs.)`?

Comment: Yes sir. That is the column name. Does the brackets cause problem?

Comment: itprice value seems to be wrong. Are you converting from a currency to a string? Seems to me the problem is there.

Comment: A little suggestion,  don't name columns like that. use something like item_price_in_rs, because it will be very annoying whenever you try to map these columns to class properties

Comment: Yes. I've used the message box in the try catch, and the message box does show that error.

Comment: `[Quantity]='470'` looks like its a string and it should be an `int`

Comment: Ok thanks to all, i'm gonna rename the column now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL doesn't use square brackets:

```
UPDATE inventory Set [Item Name]=@itname
```

It uses back-ticks:

```
UPDATE inventory Set `Item Name`=@itname
```

Keep in mind that the "error in your SQL syntax" message always points to the *exact* character at which the SQL parser first became confused.  The very start of what it's "near".  In this case that `[` character.

Comment: Yes, That's it. You are a life saver...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse string for int columns:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", int.Parse(txtbox_qty.Text));
```

Comment: @asdf even though mysql casts string to int for you it's a bad practice. It's better to validate and cast values before invoking SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

MySql doesn't use brackets. put within backticks

```
`Item Price (in Rs.)`
```

The `CommandText` should be something like this

```
UPDATE inventory Set `Item Name`=@itname,`Quantity Type`=@qtype,`Quantity`=@qty,`Item Price (in Rs.)`=@itprice,`Supplier`=@supl WHERE `pid`=@lpid
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace [ and ] by back ticks (`)the following line: 
command.CommandText = "UPDATE inventory Set [Item Name]=@itname,[Quantity Type]=@qtype,[Quantity]=@qty,[Item Price (in Rs.)]=@itprice,[Supplier]=@supl WHERE [pid]=@lpid";